# Parallel run for this particular powershell script

Tags: powershell

I am in the process of re-writing the script below to be able to run in parallel, as can be seen in the code, an array of servers is passed to the script, and then it loads it onto a hash table, loops through each server at a time to do the deployment, for each server there are files to execute in a particular order (see array of files). Looking at the structure, I feel workspace is the way to go here but I could be wrong.

Where the performance gains can be seen in my opinion or having the code such that multiple servers can be executed at thesame time rather than waiting for each server to complete and move onto the next one. foreach parallel

I ran a test to call a function declared outside a workspace, it worked.Is this good practice to call a function declared outside a workspace ? I ask this because I would like to reuse some functions outside the workspace, or is it generally better to put all the code in the workspace even ones that are not intended for parallel workloads i.e one off calls to the code. ?

The below is the code I am testing with.

```
Function Check-Instance-Connection{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                    ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                    Position=0)]
                    $sql_server,                    

                    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                    ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                    Position=1)]
                    $db_name         
    )

    try
    {
        #Return extra useful info by using custom objects
        $check_outcome = "" | Select-Object -Property log_date, stage, status, error_message             
        $check_outcome.log_date = (Get-Date)
        $check_outcome.stage = 'Ping SQL instance for $sql_server'

        #test connection for a sql instance
        $connectionstring = "Data Source=$sql_server;Integrated Security =true;Initial Catalog=$db_name;Connect Timeout=5;"
        $sqllconnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $connectionstring
        $sqllconnection.Open();
        $check_outcome.status = $true
        $check_outcome.error_message = ''

        return $check_outcome

    }
    Catch
    {   
        $check_outcome.status = $false
        $check_outcome.error_message = $_.Exception.Message
        return $check_outcome

    }

    finally{
        $sqllconnection.Close();              

    }
}







$file_list = @("deployment_1.sql","deployment_2.sql","deployment_3.sql","deployment_4.sql","deployment_5.sql")

$x = (1,"Server1",3,1),(4,"Server2",6,2),(3,"Server3",4,3)
$k = 'serverid','servername','locationid','appid'    # key names correspond to data positions in each array in $x
$h = @{}
  
  
For($i=0;$i -lt $x[0].length; $i++){
    $x |
        ForEach-Object{
            [array]$h.($k[$i]) += [string]$_[$i]
        }
           
           
} 

$folder = "F:\Files\"
$database_name = "Test"


foreach ($server_id in $all_server_ids)
{
    $severid = $h["serverid"][$all_server_ids.indexof($server_id)]
    $servername =  $h["servername"][$all_server_ids.indexof($server_id)]
    $locationid =  $h["locationid"][$all_server_ids.indexof($server_id)]

    $message = 'ServerID {0} has a servername of  {1} and a location id of {2}'  -f $server_id, $h["servername"][$all_server_ids.indexof($server_id)],$h["locationid"][$all_server_ids.indexof($server_id)]
    Write-Output $message
    Write-Output "This $severid and this $servername and this $locationid"
    
    foreach ($file in $file_list)
    {
    
        $is_instance_ok = Check-Instance-Connection $servername $database_name
        if ($is_instance_ok.check_outcome -eq $true){
            invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance "$servername" -inputfile $folder$file  -Database  "$database_name" -Querytimeout 60 -OutputSqlErrors $true -ConnectionTimeout 10 -ErrorAction Continue -Errorvariable generated_error | Out-Null
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: In PowerShell v5 you can use Workflow, and or Jobs to do parallel processing. This is covered in the PowerShell help files. In PowerShell Core v7, you can use the new ForEach -parallel option.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I did a lot more research and looked at a lot of examples on how workflows work. This is what I have come up with.

```
Workflow RunExecution
    { 



Function Check-Instance-Connection{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                    ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                    Position=0)]
                    $sql_server,                    

                    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                    ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                    Position=1)]
                    $db_name         
    )

    try
    {
        #Return extra useful info by using custom objects
        $check_outcome = "" | Select-Object -Property log_date, stage, status, error_message             
        $check_outcome.log_date = (Get-Date)
        $check_outcome.stage = 'Ping SQL instance for $sql_server'

        #test connection for a sql instance
        $connectionstring = "Data Source=$sql_server;Integrated Security =true;Initial Catalog=$db_name;Connect Timeout=5;"
        $sqllconnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $connectionstring
        $sqllconnection.Open();
        $check_outcome.status = $true
        $check_outcome.error_message = ''

        return $check_outcome

    }
    Catch
    {   
        $check_outcome.status = $false
        $check_outcome.error_message = $_.Exception.Message
        return $check_outcome

    }

    finally{
        $sqllconnection.Close();              

    }
}



$file_list = @("deployment_1.sql","deployment_2.sql","deployment_3.sql","deployment_4.sql","deployment_5.sql")

$x = (1,"server1\DEV3",3,1),(4,"serer1\DEV2",6,2),(3,"serer2\DEV1",4,3)
$k = 'serverid','servername','locationid','appid'     
$h = @{}
  
  
For($i=0;$i -lt $x[0].length; $i++){
    $x |
        ForEach-Object{
            [array]$h.($k[$i]) += [string]$_[$i]
        }
           
           
} 

$folder = "C:\Temp\"
$database_name = "Test"
$all_server_ids = $h['serverid']


    foreach -parallel ($server_id in $all_server_ids)
    {
        $severid = $h["serverid"][$all_server_ids.indexof($server_id)]
        $servername =  $h["servername"][$all_server_ids.indexof($server_id)]
        $locationid =  $h["locationid"][$all_server_ids.indexof($server_id)]

        foreach ($file in $file_list)
        {
        


            # $check_fine = $is_instance_ok.check_outcome 
            # if ($check_fine = $true){
                invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance "$servername" -inputfile $folder$file  -Database  "$database_name" -Querytimeout 60 -OutputSqlErrors $true -ConnectionTimeout 10 -ErrorAction Continue 
                write-output  "invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance $servername -inputfile $folder$file  -Database  $database_name -Querytimeout 60 -OutputSqlErrors $true -ConnectionTimeout 10 -ErrorAction Continue "
 
#            }
        }
        
    }
}

RunExecution
```

Comment: I realised that I cannot run this within the workflow `if ($check_fine = $true)` . I wonder if there is a workaround here. Could I possibly convert the output from the custom object to a string instead of a bool and use a -eq instead ?

Comment: `-eq` works on any type of object, not just string. Assuming `$is_instance_ok` contains the output from `Check-Internet-Connection`, your `if` condition should be `if ($is_instance_ok.status){...}`